# Canvas sine wave direction

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw a simple sine wave in a canvas but I can not change the direction of the animation to vertical (from top to bottom). Tell me how can I do this?

**Javascript code**

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canv');
var $ = c.getContext('2d');

var w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

var lineOffset = 60;

var draw = function(a, b, t) {

  $.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  $.lineWidth = 0.2;

  for (var i = -70; i < 70; i += 1) {
    $.strokeStyle = 'red';
    $.beginPath();
    $.moveTo(0, h / 2);
    
    for (var j = 0; j < w; j += 10) {
      $.lineTo(lineOffset * Math.sin(i / 10) +
        j + 0.008 * j * j,
        Math.floor(h / 2 + j / 2 *
          Math.sin(j / 50 - t / 50 - i / 118) +
          (i * 0.9) * Math.sin(j / 25 - (i + t) / 65)));
    };

    $.stroke();
  }

}
var t = 0;

var run = function() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
 t += 2;
 draw(33, 52 * Math.sin(t / 2400), t);
};
run();
```

```html
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the draw function I've changed w with h and viceversa.

I've changed `$.moveTo(0,h / 2)` to `$.moveTo(w / 2,0);`

in the for loop I've changed the value for x with the value for y and viceversa.

I hope this is what you need.

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canv');
var $ = c.getContext('2d');

var w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = c.height = window.innerHeight;

var lineOffset = 60;

var draw = function(a, b, t) {

  $.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  $.lineWidth = 0.2;

  for (var i = -70; i < 70; i += 1) {
    $.strokeStyle = 'red';
    $.beginPath();
    $.moveTo(w / 2,0);
    
    
    /*
    for (var j = 0; j < w; j += 10) {
      $.lineTo(lineOffset * Math.sin(i / 10) +
        j + 0.008 * j * j,
        Math.floor(h / 2 + j / 2 *
          Math.sin(j / 50 - t / 50 - i / 118) +
          (i * 0.9) * Math.sin(j / 25 - (i + t) / 65)));
    };
    */
    
    for (var j = 0; j < h; j += 10) {
      let y = lineOffset * Math.sin(i / 10) +
        j + 0.008 * j * j;
      
      let x = Math.floor(w / 2 + j / 2 *
          Math.sin(j / 50 - t / 50 - i / 118) +
          (i * 0.9) * Math.sin(j / 25 - (i + t) / 65))
      $.lineTo(x,y);
    };
    
    

    $.stroke();
  }

}
var t = 0;

var run = function() {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
 t += 2;
 draw(33, 52 * Math.sin(t / 2400), t);
};
run();
```

```html
<canvas id='canv'></canvas>
```